# select elements in memory-object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a memory object where I store almost 2,000 `<tr>` elements. I select certain elements from this object and add them to the page according to the user.
the structure is almost like this but with more `<td>`s:

```
<tr attribute1="value" attribute2="value">
     <td class="class1">something</td>
     <td class="class1">something</td>
     <td class="class2">something</td>
     <td>
          <div class="class1">
               somthing
          </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

So I select rows on certain attributes and then want to `.show()` or `.hide()` some of the `<td>`
I tried to use the following:

```
$(myObject).find("[attribute1=value]").clone().find(".class1").show();
```

but this statement only returns the `<td>`s or `<div>`s that satisfy the class condition.

If these rows where not in memory I could easily use a select statement which will work perfectly:

```
$(".class1").hide/show()
```

How can I achieve that in my situation

Comment: `$(myObject).find("[attribute1=value]").clone().find(".class1").parente().show();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I think he wants to hide class2 and show class1 only. Your code will show the entire TR with all TDs.. I Still confuse what he is trying to achive :)

Comment: .parent() doesn't work. because it might return a <tr> which is a good thing, but it might return a <td> depending the element containing the class. I updated the question :)